# GCP - Wordpress Homepage not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have just deployed a wordpress image on GCP Compute Engine and whenever I go to the site's IP address it just shows the standard apache "It works!" page but all other links on the site are working.

Site IP - http://<>

/wp-admin works fine and, for example, the Hello World post works (http://<>/index.php/2017/05/21/hello-world/)

When I go to /var/www/html/index.php I get:

```
<?php
define('W_USE_THEMES', true);

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot but will post answer.

If you ls in /var/www/html/ you will see a file: debiandefault_index.html which overrides the index.php file. You will need to run the command:

```
sudo rm debiandefault_index.html
```

Then it will work